# Problem on Hooking Keyboard Messages using SetWindowsHookEx

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi

I 'm trying to hook on Keyboard Messages without any success.

I create a test console win32 app:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HOOKPROC hHookProc;
HINSTANCE hinstDLL; 
HHOOK hHook; 

hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("pathtodll\\KeyHook.dll")); 
hHookProc= (HOOKPROC)GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "HookProc"); 

hHook = SetWindowsHookEx( 
    WH_KEYBOARD,
    hHookProc,
    hinstDLL,
    0);

    while (1) {}

return 0;
}
```

I've also created a test win32 dll with the HookProc function:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(
  int nCode, 
  WPARAM wParam, 
  LPARAM lParam
)
{
   // process event
   //...
     MessageBox( NULL,
                TEXT("OK"),
                TEXT("OK"),
                MB_OK);

   return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Everything compiles fine but when I'm trying to debug, it seems that HookProc is never called. Actually in Win 7 the app hangs when i press any key, while in Win Xp HookProc is not called. I do get not NULL hinstDLL, hHookProc, hHook.

What am I misssing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of performing a blank while loop after calling `SetWindowsHookEx()`, try having the loop pump the calling thread's message queue instead, via `Peek/GetMessage()`. Some hooks run in the context of the thread that installs them, so the OS has to be able to switch to that thread when needed.

Comment: Like I said, some hooks run in the context of the thread that installs them.  When such a hook is called, in order to switch to the correct thread context, the OS uses the thread's message queue, and thus the thread has to pump its message queue regularly for new messages so the hook can run.

Comment: The thing is that GetMessage() never returns but as far as i am concerned it do creates the message queue at the first call. I'm trying to find some documentation that explains all these stuff but I can't find something specific and the part of msdn documentation about hooks does not says something about the need of a message queue.

Comment: See the following comment for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985.aspx "This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop".

Comment: I used WH_KEYBOARD not WH_KEYBOARD_LL though :D

Comment: I realize that, but the same restriction applies.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues here:

```
while (1) {}
```

Don't do this: your code now has a busy (infinite) loop that will effectively make the app unresponsive (and probably make the whole desktop seem sluggish too). The reason that GetMessage works here is simply because it hands control back to the OS, which will put the thread to sleep instead of running busily. You'll probably get the same effect just by calling Sleep(...), which will also return control back to the OS but without pumping messages. For test code, something like getchar() can work well here, it will gracefully block till you hit Enter in the console window. MessageBox() can also work here.

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(
{
  MessageBox( NULL,
            TEXT("OK"),
            TEXT("OK"),
            MB_OK);
```

Another problem: you generally never want to do anything 'complex' in a hook callback - just do the bare minimum to process the message, and return ASAP. You certainly don't ever want to block, which is what MessageBox does. For debugging purposes, OutputDebugString() or some other debug-oriented API that doesn't block is the way to go.